# Why is the length of the buttons longer in Firefox 4 than IE9 and Chrome 11, how should it be fixed?

Tags: css

Css:

```
button, button.btnBlue, button.btnRed, button.btnGreen, button.btnOrange, button.btnPink {
margin-left: 2px !important;
margin-right: 2px !important;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 3px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 3px;
height:25px;
border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  cursor:pointer;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:visible; /* fixes width in IE7 */
  outline:0 none /* removes focus outline in IE */
}

button::-moz-focus-inner, button::-moz-focus-inner.btnBlue, button::-moz-focus-inner.btnRed, button::-moz-focus-inner.btnGreen, button::-moz-focus-inner.btnOrange, button::-moz-focus-inner.btnPink {
border:none;
}
/* removes focus outline in FF */

button:hover, button:focus, button:hover.btnBlue,button:focus.btnBlue, button:hover.btnRed,button:focus.btnRed, button:hover.btnGreen,button:focus.btnGreen, button:hover.btnOrange,button:focus.btnOrange,button:hover.btnPink,button:focus.btnPink {
  box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

button {
font:normal 13px arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  color:#000;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background-color:#f6f6f6;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #fff, #efefef);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #efefef);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#fff), to(#efefef));
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#ffffff, endColorStr=#efefef);
}

button:hover, button:focus {
border-color:#999;
  background-color:#f0f1f3;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ebebeb);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ebebeb);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#fff), to(#ebebeb));
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#ffffff, endColorStr=#ebebeb);
}

button:active {
 background-color:#ddd;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #ccc, #fff);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ccc, #fff);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#ccc), to(#fff));
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#cccccc, endColorStr=#ffffff);
}
/* End Defulat button */
/* Blue Button */
button.btnBlue {
font:normal 13px arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  color:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid #415999;
  background-color:#3d5699;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #4465ba, #043fdb);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #4465ba, #043fdb);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#4465ba), to(#043fdb));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#4465ba,endColorStr=#043fdb);
}

button:hover.btnBlue,button:focus.btnBlue{
/* removes focus outline in FF */
border-color:#415ca3;
   background-color:#44557f;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #4b63a0, #2b5cdb);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #4b63a0, #2b5cdb);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#4b63a0), to(#2b5cdb));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#4b63a0,endColorStr=#2b5cdb);
}

button:active.btnBlue {
 background-color:#3d5699;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #4465ba, #043fdb);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #4465ba, #043fdb);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#4465ba), to(#043fdb));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#4465ba,endColorStr=#043fdb);
}
/* End Blue Button */
/* red Button */
button.btnRed {
font:normal 13px arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  color:white;
  border:1px solid #995441;
  background-color:#99503d;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #ba5d44, #db3104);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ba5d44, #db3104);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#ba5d44), to(#db3104));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#ba5d44,endColorStr=#db3104);
}

button:hover.btnRed,button:focus.btnRed{
/* removes focus outline in FF */
border-color:#a35641;
   background-color:#7f5144;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #a05d4b, #db512b);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #a05d4b, #db512b);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#a05d4b), to(#db512b));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#a05d4b,endColorStr=#db512b);
}

button:active.btnRed {
 background-color:#99503d;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #ba5d44, #db3104);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ba5d44, #db3104);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#ba5d44), to(#db3104));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#ba5d44,endColorStr=#db3104);
}
/* End red Button */
/* Green Button */
button.btnGreen {
font:normal 13px arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  color:#000000;
  border:1px solid #599941;
  background-color:#56993d;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #65ba44, #3fdb04);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #65ba44, #3fdb04);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#65ba44), to(#3fdb04));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#65ba44,endColorStr=#3fdb04);
}

button:hover.btnGreen,button:focus.btnGreen{
/* removes focus outline in FF */
border-color:#5ca341;
   background-color:#557f44;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #63a04b, #5cdb2b);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #63a04b, #5cdb2b);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#63a04b), to(#5cdb2b));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#63a04b,endColorStr=#5cdb2b);
}

button:active.btnGreen {
 background-color:#56993d;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #65ba44, #3fdb04);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #65ba44, #3fdb04);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#65ba44), to(#3fdb04));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#65ba44,endColorStr=#3fdb04);
}
/* End Green Button */
/* Orange Button */
button.btnOrange {
font:normal 13px arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  color:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid #996a41;
  background-color:#99683d;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #ba7b44, #db6804);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ba7b44, #db6804);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#ba7b44), to(#db6804));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#ba7b44,endColorStr=#db6804);
}

button:hover.btnOrange,button:focus.btnOrange{
/* removes focus outline in FF */
border-color:#a36e41;
   background-color:#7f6044;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #a0734b, #db7d2b);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #a0734b, #db7d2b);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#a0734b), to(#db7d2b));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#a0734b,endColorStr=#db7d2b);
}

button:active.btnOrange {
 background-color:#99683d;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #ba7b44, #db6804);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ba7b44, #db6804);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#ba7b44), to(#db6804));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#ba7b44,endColorStr=#db6804);
}
/* End Orange Button */
/* pink button */
button.btnPink {
font:normal 13px arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  color:#000000;
  border:1px solid #994154;
  background-color:#993d50;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #ba445e, #db0432);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ba445e, #db0432);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#ba445e), to(#db0432));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#ba445e,endColorStr=#db0432);
}

button:hover.btnPink,button:focus.btnPink{
/* removes focus outline in FF */
border-color:#a34156;
   background-color:#7f4451;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #a04b5d, #db2b51);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #a04b5d, #db2b51);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#a04b5d), to(#db2b51));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#a04b5d,endColorStr=#db2b51);
}

button:active.btnPink {
 background-color:#993d50;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #ba445e, #db0432);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ba445e, #db0432);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,from(#ba445e), to(#db0432));
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#ba445e,endColorStr=#db0432);
}
/* End pink Button */
```

Html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btnRed">Cancel</button><button type="submit">Back</button><button type="submit" class="btnBlue">Continue</button>
```

I have been messing with this for about 3 hours and i can't seem to find whats wrong.

Answer (score 6):

[Because browsers don't render the same](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/) :)

In all seriousness though, if you don't want to spend the next 3 hours trying various hacks, refreshes and frustration, use an image. If you have a lot, sprite 'em.

Comment: I would agree with @alex. Spend your time doing far more productive things than seeking that magical paradise of everything working perfectly all the time in everything that takes untold hours and yields very little, if any, real results.

Answer (score 3):

Just guessing: You set a height for the buttons, but not a width.

So the width depends upon the font size, which in Firefox is bigger than in most other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "padding:0;" to "button::-moz-focus-inner"

Answer (score 1):

Don't set an explicit width on the buttons using width, use the padding left and padding right to control the desired width and will work fine. (may have to use display:inline-block too), bit hard to tell without the desired markup

For example, rather than
.button1 {width: 200px;} use .button {padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;}